# Problem on $2$-colorable family of sets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Definition. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of some finite set.  Can we
> color the elements of the underlying set in red and blue so that no
> member of $\mathcal{F}$ will be monochromatic? Such families are
> called $2$-*colorable*.
>
> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an arbitrary family of subsets  of a finite set,
> each of which has at least two elements. If every two non-disjoint
> member of $\mathcal{F}$ share at least two common elements, prove that $\mathcal{F}$
> is $2$-colorable.

I was wondering how to solve that problem? I've tried to do it by contradiction but it did not give any results.
I know that when someone creates a post he needs to show some work but in my case I cannot do that since I do not have any idea.

Comment: You can show that you can color greedily. Suppose you already colored some vertices and suppose by contradiction that the next vertex you want to color can't be colored in any way. Can you infer a contradiction from it?

Comment: @caduk, I am thinking on this problem couple days but no ideas yet. Maybe you can show the whole proof and I'll appreciate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We color vertices one by one as long as we don't end with a uniformly colored edge. Suppose we already colored vertices $1$ to $k$. We now want to color vertex $k+1$. If we color $k+1$ with color 1 (resp. 2), the only possibility to end up with a uniformly colored edge is if there exists an edge containing $k+1$ where all vertices (except $k+1$) are already colored with color 1 (resp. 2). So the only way we can't choose a color is if there exist two edges both containing $k+1$, and both having all vertices (except $k+1$) already colored the same, one edge with color 1 and the other with color 2.
Suppose by contradiction we end up in this situation. It follows that these two edges share exactly vertex $k+1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: The first question which arises is the following: when you say "Suppose by contradiction.." what are you proving namely by contradiction? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I think that some details should be added because it is not so clear to me. 1) what are you proving by contradiction? 2) how you obtained that there two such edges? Sorry but it is not clear at all

Comment: @PlayGame I added some precisions

Comment: Let me rephrase your proof in my own words. So we have a vertex set of hypergraph $V=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and we have $2$ colors: red and blue. We color $1\in V$ arbitrarily  and we proceed to color the next vertex in such a way that no member of $\mathcal{F}$ is monochromatic.

Comment: Suppose that we colored $1,\dots,k$ (in such a way that members of $\mathcal{F}$ containing $1,\dots,k$ are not monochromatic) and we want to color $k+1$ in such a way that no member of $\mathcal{F}$ containing $\{1,\dots,k+1\}$ is monochromatic. I claim that due to our restrictions this is always possible. Indeed, suppose it is not possible. Then it implies that if we color $k+1$ in red we'll find $A\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $k+1\in A$ and $A\setminus\{k+1\}$ is colored in red. The same with blue color, i.e.

Comment: if we color $k+1$ in blue we'll find $B\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $k+1\in B$ and $B\setminus\{k+1\}$ is colored in blue. Hence $k+1\in A\cap B$ and we claim that $A\cap B=\{k+1\}$. How to prove the last equality? I am a bit confused

Comment: @PlayGame Every vertex of $A\setminus\{k+1\}$ has a different color than every vertex of $B\setminus\{k+1\}$, so all the vertices $A\setminus\{k+1\}$ are distinct from the vertices of $B\setminus\{k+1\}$.

Comment: It is clear that elements of $A\setminus\{k+1\}$ have red color and elements of $B\setminus\{k+1\}$ have blue color. However, these sets are obtained whether $k+1$ is red or blue. So it is not so clear that corresponding vertices of $A\setminus\{k+1\}$ are distinct from $B\setminus\{k+1\}$

Comment: @PlayGame When we choose a color for $k+1$, we don't modify the colors of vertices that have already a color.

Comment: We claim that $A\cap B=\{k+1\}$ because $A\setminus \{k+1\}$ is colored in red and $B\setminus \{k+1\}$ is colored in blue.  Since they do not contain $k+1$ it means that they have been colored in a previous step and these vertices are distinct. Right?

Comment: @PlayGame correct

Comment: Thank you! I accept your answer! +1